# destruction of container of QGlyphRuns fails

Tags: visual-c++, qt4

I'm trying to navigate through the set of glyphs in QTextEdit widget, but cannot overcome the following issue: after the list of QGlyphRuns is retrieved, it cannot be destuctured.

Here is the code for getting list of QGlyphRuns:

```
QTextDocument* doc = ui->textEdit->document();
QTextBlock block = doc->begin();
while(block.isValid())
{
    QTextLayout* tl = block.layout();
    {
        QList<QGlyphRun> glyphs = tl->glyphRuns();
        // the exception raises here, upon exiting the block
    }       
    block = block.next();
}
```

When glyphs is getting destructed I get _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID assertion failed. I've been trying a several ways to launch the code above:

- simple slot
- slot handled in a separate thread (with and without use of moveToThread function)
- as an event handler (the event is fired by postEvent method of QApplicaiton)

But none of those helped to get rid of the exception. The only case when it doesn't arise is when the code above is called from MainWindows constructor (after calling ui->setupUI()).

I'm using QT 4.8 non-commercial with MSVC++2010 express. Does anybody have a clue why it happens? And how to workaround it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your code structured like this:

```
do
{
//... 
}
while(block.isValid());
```

instead of

```
while(block.isValid())
{
//...
}
```

In the former case, the code is run at least once because the validity is checked only after the code block, so I'm guessing you are getting the exception in the case that the very first block is invalid. If you change it to the latter format, the code will just be skipped if the first block is invalid.

Comment: hi, teukkam,
Yes, thanks for pointing me to it. By some reason I assumed that there must always be at least one valid block (since this function is called when the context of the textedit is changed). But this is not correct because erasing the contents is also a change.
I have corrected the code, but this bug seems to be not related to the original problem, since the the exception still arises.
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the problem is caused by use of "release" QT libraries in "debug" version of the project. After switching to the "debug" version the exception has gone.